# Mobile Safari/Chrome - flutter web - failing to load - blank

Tags: flutter, safari, mobile-safari, flutter-web

My Flutter app has successfully been deployed via Firebase. I can access to any laptop browsers

On Mobile Browsers, it is failing and not able to see any error messages.

What could be root cause of a flutter web not functioning on Mobiles web browser?